# Why do rich put their money in gold

Tags: gold

I have been listening to Robert Kiyosaki (author of rich dad poor dad) podcasts and I always hear him say `the rich put their money in gold`. He never says why though. So, I am just curious to know why the rich put their money in gold.

Comment: You're working under the assumption that what he says is true.  Don't do that.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Kiyosaki#Criticism_and_controversy

Comment: Also, define `their money`, as in **how much** of `their money`?  For example, I purchased gold bullion.  That doesn't tell you **how much** gold bullion I purchased.

Comment: Who exactly are "the rich"?  I would be very supprised to learn that any significant number of wealthy Americans invested in gold (other than jewelry and so on).   In some other countries, of course, political instability makes it more attractive.

Comment: It's not his money, he can say whatever he wants, you need to think for yourself on this. The fact that as @RonJohn said you are assuming he is right is the problem.

Comment: I have never heard him say that the rich put their money in gold, his ususal spill is that the rich put their money into building businesses and in investing, particularly investing in property.

Comment: No good question or investing approach begins with "I have been listening to Robert Kiyosaki". The very premise of the question is incorrect.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer I can disprove that. "I have been listening to Robert Kiyosaki and have decided to do the opposite of what he says as an investment technique."

Comment: @ceejayoz - I tip my hat to your superior logic.

Comment: It's a shame that this question is getting dragged into focus on the specific commentator the OP mentioned, because it strikes me that there's a reasonably valuable (if basic) question buried here: why would someone put money in gold?

Comment: @dwizum - perhaps, but there are other questions. One is “Why does Gold have value?” - I can find it and add a link when I am at desktop. Gold questions are fine, but new ones risk being duplicates as we’ve had quite a few. NOTE - the FAQ is now updated with a few of the top Gold questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does gold have value?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/1767/why-does-gold-have-value)

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer agreed, good point. Even if salvaged from the notorious personality aspect, it is almost certainly a duplicate.

Answer (score 22):

I suspect he claims "the rich" put their money in gold so that you'll sign up for whatever gold service he's pitching on his podcast using his coupon code.

Answer (score 6):

I can't speak to the accuracy of Kiyosaki's belief that rich put their money in gold but there are a number of reasons that people  do so.

The most obvious is that people think that it's a timely speculation or investment.

Others believe that it's a  store of value and and is therefore a safe investment in times of uncertainty.  It's  widely viewed as an inflation hedge,  protecting against purchasing power risk.

Then there are the gold bugs, many of which oppose fiat currency, distrust the banking system or ascribe to various conspiracy theories such as the imminent collapse of the world economy.  They're a bit of a fringe element.

Comment: And gold bugs certainly aren't wealthy.

Comment: That's for sure.  Gold newsletters were popular long before the internet and there's no shortage of online variations now as well as the barrage of relatively worthless gold plated coins hawked in TV commercials.

Answer (score 2):

Such statement is constructed in a way that when person who have 10 billions would put one dollar in gold (buying some jewellery on flea market) it would be true. A rich person put their money in gold.

Here you can find a nice chart showing in what REALLY rich people put money in. 
https://www.visualcapitalist.com/chart-assets-make-wealth/
Gold is liquid asset. Notice how percentage of wealth invested in such lowers with net worth. Yet the $1B is still larger than what $100K would have "in gold".

Answer (score 2):

In 2015, Robert Kiyosaki [predicted a global financial crash in 2016](https://www.rappler.com/business/features/114622-robert-kiyosaki-market-crash-2016) and advised people to prepare for that crash by converting their assets into gold. Kiyosaki's rhetoric trademark is to frame all his advice as "Rich people do X, so you should do X". According to his critics, the claim that all his advice is based on observing "rich people" isn't always true. So if Kiyosaki uses that phrasing, it should generally be understood as "I would personally advise you to do X".

When fiat money, stocks and other financial instruments lose value, precious metals like gold usually retain their value. However, his prediction didn't come true. It's now 3 years later and there is still no crash. So in hindsight, his advise wasn't very good.

The podcasts you listened to might be from that time. Or maybe he still believes in his theory that a big crash is imminent?

Comment: Rich people buy $5M mansions; so should you!

Comment: @RonJohn Rich people have their shell company buy the 5M mansion, which finances it through a loan from a bad-bank, have the shell company transfer ownership of the mansion to a holding company in a tax haven, declare the shell company bankrupt and then rent the mansion from the holding for $1 a month :)

Answer (score 0):

According to [current statistic](https://www.statista.com/statistics/299609/gold-demand-by-industry-sector-share/), 17% of the golds are consumed by electronics and other industrial products. 52% is made into jewellery, Gold bar, coins and central bank purchase total up 31%. If you look at the spread, Gold is hardly an investment but for leveraging.

If you live in a country like West Europe or US, holding Gold will not yield any good return. However, if you live in a high inflation country with no access to other currency leveraging tools, Gold maybe your best leveraging option.

However, Gold `derivatives` have their own catch. Since Gold price is stagnant in first world country, any jewelry that relies on the leveraging mentality actually losing money (Gold doesn't generate interest fee). So some country Jewelry shop comes out with a Ponzi scheme to make quick bucks, in which, so-called "gold investment certificate" is sold without any real deposit or Gold metal backing.

IMHO, though no statistic support, I always think chicken soup books like `rich dad poor dad` partially contribute to the subprime loan crisis. Any idea from Robert Kiyosaki is no better than [Bernard Madoff Ponzi Scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madoff_investment_scandal).